# Json conversion using Gson

Tags: json, gson

Hi I have the following class and need to convert the incoming Json using Gson

```
public class JsonConverter<T>{

private boolean success = Boolean.TRUE;
private List<T> data;
private int total;
private String message;

public JsonConverter(){

}

public JsonConverter(List<T> data, int count){
    this.data = data;
    this.total = count;
} //getters and setters
```

I have an incoming Json with a data property that contains the values of some a class which has the following definition:

```
class A {private long calendarId;
private String title;
private String description;
private int colorId;
private boolean isHidden;
private long userId; //getter and setter
```

}

Example:
Json string:

> {"data":{"calendarId":"ext-gen223","title":"work","description":"work","isHidden":false,"colorId":"2"}}

I want to get the value from **Json String** and set it inside the **List data** (which should be a **list of Class A objects**) of Class JsonConverter using Gson.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `Type type = new TypeToken<JsonConverter<A>>(){}.getType();` and got it running!