# spring:escapeBody results in invalid JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp

I am attempting to escape a string in a JSP to return valid JSON on an AJAX call however the spring:escapeBody tag is not correctly escaping single quotes for JSON. Valid JSON should not escape single quotes.

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" contentType="json/application"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
{
"status": "success",
"body" : "<spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true"> 
           if you don't have "user" an account
           </spring:escapeBody>"
 }
```

so this code evaluates to:

```
{
"status": "success",
"body" : "if you don\'t have \"user\" an account"
 }
```

but valid JSON needs it to be:

```
{
"status": "success",
"body" : "if you don't have \"user\" an account"
 }
```

is there anyway I can not escape the single quote with the escapeBody tag? 
Or is there another tag I can use? maybe a JSTL function?

Comment: This is a very unusual way to get a JSON response. Why are you not returning a object from a controller and let Jackson handle the JSON writing?

Comment: This is a slight simplification of my actual code, I am actually attempting to return a existing tag file in the body of the JSON Object (the tag contains single quotes that aren't escaping). Would I be able to escape a tag file correctly in the controller and then return the escaped HTML/Javascript?

Comment: @Bart thanks for pointing out the fact that this is an unsual way to get a JSON response. I guess everyone should stay away from `spring:escapeBody` and look into "Java to JSON best practices" and "java to json best libraries", ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Ryan in the (very good) comments of Sotirios Delimanolis's answer:

- The [Javascript Object Notation specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) states that `Any character may be escaped`. So obviously this means that even single quotes characters can be.
- However as pointed out by Ryan (again in the same comments), this is raised as an error by jQuery's Ajax implementation. see [jQuery.parseJSON throws “Invalid JSON” error due to escaped single quote in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

So it seems like it's simply an implementation choice that is now leaving us with a standard that's not really consistently implemented... sigh

Anyway, here is a work around you can use to get your code working

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" contentType="json/application"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%-- 
    [1] Removing the escape of the single quote character: jQuery's Ajax cannot handle it
            stackoverflow.com/questions/25491391/springescapebody-results-in-invalid-json
            stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response
--%>
<c:set var="someJsonData" >
    <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true"> 
               if you don't have "user" an account
    </spring:escapeBody>
</c:set>    
{
    "status": "success",
    "body" : "${fn:replace(someJsonData, "\\\'","'")}" , <%-- [1] --%>
}
```

[Here is the `JSTL fn` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Probably not the cleanest/best solution to be honest. But it does the job until you find better.

Comment: `So obviously this means that even single quotes characters can be` - No, it is implementation-dependent. See my comment.

Comment: Weird, this is all so unclear.. We should not even have to debate about this

Answer (score 3):

The [Javascript Object Notation specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) states that

> Any character may be escaped.

As such,

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "body" : "if you don\'t have \"user\" an account"
}
```

is valid JSON.

If you need to create really custom text, you'll need to generate it yourself in a controller handler method or other component.

Ideally, you would use a `@ResponseBody` annotated method with a POJO that represents your status/body JSON object.

Comment: Thats what I assumed as well however if you paste that json into any json parser it will throw an error on the escaped single quote, as will your browser.

Comment: @Ryan [This jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wtkqhsLy/2/) works just fine, so does parsing the same JSON with Gson, Jackson, and org.json. I'll accept that jsonlint fails, but that seems like a bug.

Comment: @Ryan Basically, `'` doesn't need to be escaped, but it _can_. `escapeBody` is not the right tool for this. Use a proper serialization component. A JSON view or `@ResponseBody` with an appropriate POJO. If the JSP needs to be imported by another, create your own tag or generate the JSON and add it to the model.

Comment: your right, I guess my issue is that jQuery is being picky about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes, but *May* is interpreted per [RFC 2119](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119): `This word, or the adjective "OPTIONAL", mean that an item is truly optional`. So JSON with an escaped single quote may be valid JSON, but it may not, depending upon the implementation.

Comment: @JustinEthier The same RFC states that there must be some interoperability between implementations that do and don't include it [the escaping of all characters]. There doesn't seem to be any here (jQuery and jsonlint).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes, but it includes weasel words `though perhaps with reduced functionality`. If you try using your browser's `JSON.parse` function to parse `"\'"` it will raise a syntax error - perhaps that could be considered interop in the sense that it detects an unhandled case and reports an error.

Comment: @JustinEthier Bleh. I thought this spec was rock solid.