# how to convert a Java POJO to JSON string?

Tags: java, json, conventions

I hava a POJO for which i set values, the pojo is:

```
public class CreateRequisitionRO extends AbstractPortfolioSpecificRO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2418929142185068821L;

    private BigDecimal transSrlNo;
    private String transCode;
    private InflowOutflow inflowOutflow;

public BigDecimal getTransSrlNo() {
        return transSrlNo;
    }

    public void setTransSrlNo(BigDecimal transSrlNo) {
        this.transSrlNo = transSrlNo;
    }

    public InflowOutflow getInflowOutflow() {
        return inflowOutflow;
    }

    public void setInflowOutflow(InflowOutflow inflowOutflow) {
        this.inflowOutflow = inflowOutflow;
    }
    public String getTransCode() {
        return transCode;
    }
}
```

This is how i set values :

```
CreateRequisitionRO[] request = new CreateRequisitionRO[1];
    request[0].setTransSrlNo(new BigDecimal(1));
    request[0].setTransCode("BUY");
    request[0].setInflowOutflow(InflowOutflow.I);

now i would like to convert/serialize the above java pojo to Json string.
```

Could some body help me how to do this?

Best Regards

Comment: Would the answers in this question work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) or [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), as mentioned in the other answer, will sort you. Follow the [JSON tutorial on XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) and your code will look something like this:

```
        CreateRequisitionRO product = new CreateRequisitionRO();
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
        xstream.alias("product", Product.class);

        System.out.println(xstream.toXML(product));
```

With GSON, your code will [look like this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types):

```
CreateRequisitionRO obj = new CreateRequisitionRO();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Pick your library and go.

Comment: thanks a lot hd1 , tried with both the answers you have given above, but still get the same exception :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gson libary to do the favor for you