# Convert Java data in json

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a list of user objects in a Collection, but I want to convert this into JSON format so that on my html page I can read that json data by using javascript.

```
List<UserWithEmbeddedContact> users=(List<UserWithEmbeddedContact>) q.execute();
if(!users.isEmpty()) {
    for(UserWithEmbeddedContact user:users) {
        System.out.println("username="+user.getUsername()+
            " password="+user.getPassword()+" mobile="+user.getMobile());
    }
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is your answer:

From their wiki:

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Ex:

```
List<UserWithEmbeddedContact> users = (List<UserWithEmbeddedContact>) q.execute();

final Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UserWithEmbeddedContact>>(){}.getType();
final String json = new Gson().toJson(users, listType);
```

Comment: TypeToken and GSon classes are not available .So how can i import them in my package

Answer (score 0):

Use [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) for Java. It's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will convert java instance variables into `JSON`

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ObjectToJSON {
// declaring variables to be converted into JSON
private int data1 = 100;
private String data2 = "hello";
private String[] details = { "IBM", "pune", "ind", "12345" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating the class object
    ObjectToJSON obj = new ObjectToJSON();
    // Creating Gson class object
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // convert java object to JSON format and receiving the JSON String
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

}