# what is the equivalent hashmap or list structure for the below json?

Tags: java, json, collections

There is a need of Java object to JSON conversion. So I think I need help in making use of HashMap or List (Arraylist) to generate the below complicated JSON. I gave it a try, but I was not able to generate the exact JSON format.

```
{
    "uid": "prathap.b",
    "commonName": "prathap",
    "unverifiedMails": "prathap.balachandra@xyz.com",
    "alternateMobiles": "+91123456789",
    "realm": "jio",
    "deviceInfo": {
        "consumptionDeviceName": "My Desktop",
        "info": {
            "type": "browser",
            "devicePrint": {
                "screenHeight": 1080,
                "product": {
                    "sub": 20030107,
                    "name": "Gecko"
                },
                "platform": "Linuxx86_64",
                "timezone": "-¬-120",
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0(X11;Linuxx86_64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/28.0.1500.5Safari/537.36",
                "screenWidth": 1920,
                "installedPlugins": "libpepflashplayer.so;internal-¬-remoting-¬-viewer",
                "longitude": 17.003768500000003,
                "latitude": 51.110937899999996,
                "installedFonts": "AbyssinicaSIL;Amiri;AsanaMath;BitstreamCharter",
                "screenColorDepth": 24
            },
            "mobile": {
                "id_brand": "ghdh",
                "model": "on_wifi"
            }
        }
    },
    "unverifiedMobiles": "+91123412341",
    "preferredOtpMethod": "M",
    "password": "rjil@1234"
}
```

Thanks in advance

PFB the code I tried.

```
CreateUser createuser=new CreateUser();

CreateUser.DeviceInfo device=createuser.new DeviceInfo();

DeviceInfo.Info in=device.new Info();

Info.DevicePrint dp=in.new DevicePrint();

DevicePrint.Product prd=dp.new Product();

DevicePrint.Mobile mob=dp.new Mobile();


List l1=new ArrayList();
l1.add("123456789");
l1.add("987456321");
createuser.setAlternateMobiles(l1);

List l2=new ArrayList();
l2.add("123456789");
l2.add("987456321");
createuser.setUnverifiedMobiles(l2);

List l3=new ArrayList();
l3.add("abc@ril.com");
l3.add("cba@ril.com");
createuser.setUnverifiedMails(l3);

createuser.setPassword("password123");
createuser.setPreferredOtpMethod('M');
createuser.setRealm("jio");
createuser.setCommonName("prathap");
createuser.setUid("prathap.b");

device.setConsumptionDeviceName("My Desktop");

in.setType("browser");

dp.setInstalledFonts("A");
dp.setInstalledPlugins("B");
dp.setLatitude(123);
dp.setLongitude(456);
dp.setPlatform("C");
dp.setScreenColorDepth(789);
dp.setScreenHeight(10);
dp.setTimezone("D");
dp.setUserAgent("E");

prd.setName("john");
prd.setSub("F");

mob.setId_Brand("G");
mob.setModel("H");

List<CreateUser> listUser=new ArrayList<CreateUser>();     

listUser.add(createuser);

List<DeviceInfo> listdevice=new ArrayList<DeviceInfo>();   

listdevice.add(device);

TestInfo ti=new TestInfo();
ti.setInfo(in);

TestDevicePrint tdp=new TestDevicePrint();
tdp.setDevicePrint(dp);

Testproduct tp=new Testproduct();
tp.setProduct(prd);

List<Mobile> listmob=new ArrayList<Mobile>();   

listmob.add();

TestMobile tm=new TestMobile();
tm.setMobile(mob);

List<Object> Listfinal=new ArrayList<Object>();
Listfinal.add(createuser);
Listfinal.add(ti);
Listfinal.add(tdp);
Listfinal.add(tp);
Listfinal.add(tm);

Gson gson=new Gson();
String one =gson.toJson(Listfinal);

/*System.out.println("Lest chk"+one);*/
```

generated JSON:

```
[
    {
        "commonName":"prathap",
        "realm":"jio",
        "uid":"prathap.b",
        "password":"password123",
        "unverifiedMails":["abc@ril.com","cba@ril.com"],
        "unverifiedMobiles":["123456789","987456321"],
        "alternateMobiles":["123456789","987456321"],
        "preferredOtpMethod":"M"
    },
    {
        "info":{
            "type":"browser"
        }
    },
    {
        "devicePrint":{
            "screenColorDepth":789,
            "screenHeight":10,
            "screenWidth":0,
            "installedPlugins":"B",
            "installedFonts":"A",
            "timezone":"D",
            "latitude":123.0,
            "longitude":456.0,
            "userAgent":"E",
            "platform":"C"
        }
    },
    {
        "product":{
            "name":"john",
            "sub":"F"
        }
    },
    {
        "mobile":{
            "id_Brand":"G",
            "model":"H"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `I gave a try` !!! Post your code tried.

Comment: why can't you use one of many Java <-> Json mapping libraries like Gson or Jackson?

Comment: can u pls help mein terms of code to generate the exatc json?

Comment: You can use google library. [Google Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is very popular library which does this job.

Comment: @Wundwin Born...PFB the code i tried.

Comment: CreateUser createuser=new CreateUser();
            
            CreateUser.DeviceInfo device=createuser.new DeviceInfo();
            
            DeviceInfo.Info in=device.new Info();
            
            Info.DevicePrint dp=in.new DevicePrint();

Comment: DevicePrint.Product prd=dp.new Product();
            
            DevicePrint.Mobile mob=dp.new Mobile();

      
            List l1=new ArrayList();
            l1.add("123456789");
            l1.add("987456321");
      createuser.setAlternateMobiles(l1);
      
      List l2=new ArrayList();
      l2.add("123456789");
      l2.add("987456321");
      createuser.setUnverifiedMobiles(l2);
      
      List l3=new ArrayList();
      l3.add("abc@ril.com");
      l3.add("cba@ril.com");
      createuser.setUnverifiedMails(l3);
      
/

Comment: createuser.setPassword("password123");
      createuser.setPreferredOtpMethod('M');
      createuser.setRealm("jio");
      createuser.setCommonName("prathap");
      createuser.setUid("prathap.b");
      
      
      
      
      
      device.setConsumptionDeviceName("My Desktop");
      
      in.setType("browser");
      
      dp.setInstalledFonts("A");
      dp.setInstalledPlugins("B");
      dp.setLatitude(123);
      dp.setLongitude(456);
      dp.setPlatform("C");

Comment: dp.setScreenColorDepth(789);
      dp.setScreenHeight(10);
      dp.setTimezone("D");
      dp.setUserAgent("E");
      
      
      
      prd.setName("john");
      prd.setSub("F");
      
      
      
      mob.setId_Brand("G");
      mob.setModel("H");
      
      
      List<CreateUser> listUser=new ArrayList<CreateUser>();     
      
       listUser.add(createuser);
      
       List<DeviceInfo> listdevice=new ArrayList<DeviceInfo>();   
      
       listdevice.add(device);
      


TestInfo ti=new TestInfo();
ti.setInfo(in);

Comment: TestDevicePrint tdp=new TestDevicePrint();
tdp.setDevicePrint(dp);





Testproduct tp=new Testproduct();
tp.setProduct(prd);

List<Mobile> listmob=new ArrayList<Mobile>();   

listmob.add();

TestMobile tm=new TestMobile();
tm.setMobile(mob);


List<Object> Listfinal=new ArrayList<Object>();
Listfinal.add(createuser);
Listfinal.add(ti);
Listfinal.add(tdp);
Listfinal.add(tp);
Listfinal.add(tm);






Gson gson=new Gson();
String one =gson.toJson(Listfinal);
*/

/*System.out.println("Lest chk"+one);*

Comment: i know its complicated... but can u pls look into it?

Comment: https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html For start, you can think of JSON object as a sort of key value mapping.

Comment: @PrathapKb put your code by editing the post, not in comments.

Comment: @mmeverdies- done posting the code..

Comment: What is the difference between the given format and `one`?

Comment: i will update my post with the one i generated with above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you put the various components of the original object into an array and hope for it to magically become an object, when converted to JSON.

To solve this, let `CreateUser` have a field `deviceInfo` of the type `DeviceInfo`. Similarly let `DeviceInfo` have a field `info`of type `Info` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Gson library for Json. Here is link [click here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object.

Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice) to your question .