# ReactJS returns parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token a after AJAX call to JAVA servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to finish ReactJS [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) but have this error "parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token a".

I have java servlet with get and post methods, where I send response with next json:

```
"[{"author": "Pete Hunt", "text": "This is one comment"}, {"author": "Jordan Walke", "text": "This is another comment"}]"
```

Also I tried this one
    {"author": "Pete Hunt", "text": "This is one comment"}, {"author": "Jordan Walke", "text": "This is another comment"}

I don't see where is problem. For me it looks like I missed something in ReactJS

**UPD** My code for servlet response. I'm using gson library.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

ModelObject obj = new ModelObject();
obj.setAuthor("Pete Hunt");
obj.setText("This is one comment");

ModelObject obj2 = new ModelObject();
obj2.setAuthor("Jordan Walke");
obj2.setText("This is *another* comment");

List<ModelObject> objList = new ArrayList<ModelObject>();

objList.add(obj);
objList.add(obj2);

Gson gson = new Gson();

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(gson.toJson(objList));
out.close();
out.flush()
```

Comment: Remove the first and last character of the first one (the double quotes).

Comment: I have tried without them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to parse a string that is enclosed in redundant double quotes, like this:

```
JSON.parse('"[{"author": "Pete Hunt", "text": "This is one comment"}]"');
```

instead of:

```
JSON.parse(' [{"author": "Pete Hunt", "text": "This is one comment"}] ');
```

then you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token a` because it tries to parse `"[{"` as a string and doesn't expect to get a character `a` next.

You have to show the exact command that prints the JSON string but you definitely get the extra double quotes somewhere and `Unexpected token a` will become `Unexpected token X` if you change `"author"` to `"X"`.

What you are probably doing (though this is only my speculation because you haven't shown any actual code) is building the JSON string manually which is never a good idea. You should use a library like [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [json-io](https://github.com/jdereg/json-io#readme) to do it for you.

See also: [Java JSON serialization - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice) question.

Comment: I edited question with servlet code. In chrome console I can see proper array, but exception changed to Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o. From other questions I found it can be JSON double parsing. It is still unclear.