# How to write data into text file in Json format for Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I wanted write some data for a class like that

```
package com.sample.story.model;
     public class Story {   
            private String storyTitle;
            private String storyBody;
            private String storyAuthor;
               // getter setter method inculded
        }
```

I pass data from view controller.Now i want to write those data into a text file in Json format.where i should locate the text file how to store it as Json format.I created a file in servletcontext but i don,t know how read data from there .please help me to solve this problem .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code you're describing, your use case is not clear: if you just want to serialize an arbitrary object to JSON, how is Spring involved?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you need a Json serialiser.

If so, your question is already asked here: [Java JSON serialization - best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice)