# How to send post request from android to rest api?

Tags: android, json, rest, post

I need to sent json to my rest api in spring boot.
It should look like this:

```
{

    "deviceid":543 ,
    "lat": 56.78,
    "lon": 67.45,
    "date": 1501624800000,
    "time": 18000000
}
```

I'm using google volley.
I'm getting an error in android monitor:

```
[2794] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for 
http://192.168.0.137:8080/coordinates
```

And this is error form sts-spring console:

```
 2017-08-03 11:01:21.537  WARN 5056 --- [nio-8080-exec-
 6].w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'date': was expecting 
('true','false' or 'null')at [Source:java.io.PushbackInputStream@18362ba; 
line: 1, column: 6]; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:  Unrecognized token 
'date': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')at [Source: 
java.io.PushbackInputStream@18362ba; line: 1, column: 6]
```

This is my GPS service code.

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {



private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
String insertUrl = "http://192.168.0.137:8080/coordinates";

RequestQueue requestQueue;

String la_string,lo_string;
String deviceid = "987";
String date="1501624800000";
String time ="61200000";



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            //i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());
            //Intent i1 = new Intent("latitude_update");
            //Intent i2 = new Intent("longitude_update");
            i.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            i.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
            sendBroadcast(i);
            la_string=Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            lo_string=Double.toString(location.getLongitude());





            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());




            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            })

            {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("deviceid",deviceid);
                    parameters.put("lat",la_string);
                    parameters.put("lon",lo_string);
                    parameters.put("date","1501624800000");
                    parameters.put("time","18000000");


                    return parameters;
                }


                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return parameters;
                }




            };
            requestQueue.add(request);

        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //noinspection MissingPermission
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,locationListener);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}}
```

As you see date and time are hardcoded, my next question is how to convert date and time to json format?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Take a look at spring guide for consuming REST API for Android. https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

Comment: And for conversion of your data to and from JSON, make a serializeable data class, instead of using variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice

Answer (score 0):

I solved one part of my problem, but there is another one.
I sent data to the database.
When the location changes, instead of placing a new one, the old one is overwritten.
The id field in the database is auto incremental.
My post request looks like.

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

            jsonParams.put("deviceid", "1919");
            jsonParams.put("lat", la_string);
            jsonParams.put("lon", lo_string);
            jsonParams.put("date","1501624800000");
            jsonParams.put("time","18000000");
            JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, insertUrl,
                    new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //   Handle Error
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

Android sends 0 as vlue of id, and overwrites the row. 
When I use POSTMAN to generate post request and don't put id field in request database automatically increment the id filed, and put next row.
Post request for POSTMAN looks like this:

```
{
    "deviceid":455466 ,
    "lat": 56.78,
    "lon": 67.45,
    "date": 1501624800000,
    "time": 18000000
}
```